# Xamarin form :Sqlite-net-pcl not able to create primary key using string

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, package

Hello i have upgraded a package Sqlite-Net-Pcl from nuget to latest but the table created doesn't have the primary key. I am not sure is it because i defined the primary key using string instead of an int.

The previous version i have can have primary key using string not int but once upgraded the column didn't create.

Comment: we can't help you if we don't know what you're doing.  Please post the relevant code

Comment: Did you read any release notes about breaking changes?

Comment: From latest official sample.(https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net). It use int as primary key.`public class Stock
{
 [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Symbol { get; set; }
}`